# Sails.js / Nodejs / Json support for emojis

Tags: json, node.js, rest, api, sails.js

is there a way to use emojis over Sails REST api ? I have my tables with utf8mb4_unicode_ci and manually I can store correctly emojis. But on the web view and on the api response it show as a question mark "?".

Please. Any tip you have is welcome.

Thank you

More Info:

For example I hit the api with this

```
{
    "name": "hello",
    "body": "Testing on node  v6.9  x4",
    "label": "info",
    "user": 1
}
```

but the response is:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "body": "Testing on node  v6.9 ???? x4",
  "label": "info",
  "thanks": 0,
  "notUseful": 0,
  "createdAt": "2016-12-28T15:30:26.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2016-12-28T15:30:26.000Z",
  "id": 105,
  "user": 1,
  "topic": null
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the API response, and how you fetch it?

Comment: do it. Please, do you have any idea. Or do u know the proper way to work with emoticons in rest api?

Comment: sorry I'm trying to change "do it" for "done" but I'm getting this bug http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339725/users-without-the-comment-privilege-unable-to-edit-their-own-comments

Comment: is this a blueprint route? Can you please try it out with the `sails-disk` adapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you added the `charset` and `collation` settings to your MySQL configuration in `config/connections.js` or `config/local.js`?

```
someMysqlServer: {
  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  // other settings...
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
  collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
}
```

Comment: I Added the charset and collation but still not working, I am trying to select from the MySQL DB, it returns "{\"test\": \"?\"}", instead of {"test": ""} 
 node version 6.11.1, sails version 0.12, MySQL version 5.6